How would an ability that changes immunity to resistance work with damage absorption?
So I gave one of my players an ability similar to the Pyromancer subclass for sorcerer, which states:

Fiery Soul: At 18th level, you gain immunity to fire damage. In
addition, any spell or effect you create ignores resistance to fire
damage and treats immunity to fire damage as resistance to fire
damage.

Now my players are going to go up against an Iron Golem, which has the fire absorption ability:

Fire Absorption. Whenever the golem is subjected to fire damage, it
takes no damage and instead regains a number of hit points equal to
the fire damage dealt.


How would these 2 abilities interact? I have thought of a few different scenarios for when the player shoots a fire bolt at the golem and hits it.

Full immunity: Since the immunity doesn't stop the golem from absorbing the damage, resistance doesn't change anything. The golem is hit, takes no damage and heals for the full damage amount.
Partial negation: Since the golem doesn't have immunity it anymore, it only absorbs the damage it can negate through the resistance. The golem is hit and heals for half the damage rounded up, but also takes half the damage rounded down. This basically makes it so the golem takes 0 damage and either heals 1 or 0 (depending on even or odd damage)
Full negation: Since the golem no longer has immunity, its absorption ability is ignored. The golem is hit and takes half the damage rounded down because of resistance.

Since specific beats general, I feel like scenario 1 is the closest to RAW, but I would like to know if going with scenario 2 or 3 is closer to RAI for this situation.

Edit*: Some new scenarios have been suggested for possible house rules

Partial healing: Like scenario 2, the resistance is taken into account, but no damage is applied. The golem is hit, the damage is halved (rounded down) and the golem heals for that amount. This virtually halves the Fire absoption ability.
Healing vulnerability: Fiery soul is treated as "having extra hot fire", making the fire hit extra hard. The golem is hit, the damage is multiplied by 2 and the golem heals for that amount. This would be extra punishing on the player (if they are build for fire damage)


Related: How are Fireball attacks on Iron Golems resolved?

One other possible scenario is that you consider Absorption to be the next level above immunity, and have Fiery Soul "Downgrade" it to Immunity. This has virtually the same effects as #2 on your list, but with a different way of getting there.

RAW would be Full Immunity
Your suggestion that your option 1 is closest to RAW would be my take on this as well. Since the specific feature Fire Absorption trumps its general fire immunity (or resistance, in this case), it would still "absorb the fire", so to speak, and thus take no damage, healing for the damage dealt, regardless of how much fire damage it might have taken if it didn't have this feature.
"RAI" is a dangerous term here
As for whether either of the other options would be considered the designer's "intent" is anyone's guess. I could argue that the designers intended the iron golem to simply absorb fire, regardless of how "powerful" the source of the fire is (i.e. coming from a pyromancer with Fiery Soul), and that's why they gave it a feature describing this despite the fact that it already has fire immunity.
However, the other argument is that Fire Absorption is due to the fire immunity, so the designers might have intended that this feature is weakened or negated entirely should the golem lose its fire immunity for any reason. More likely, they never considered this interaction and, if confronted with it, would simply make a "ruling" (likely one of your three options), same as any DM could.
If you don't like the RAW, just houserule it
In other words, what the designers would do is anyone's guess and thus we can't tell you. However, it sounds like you simply want to houserule it to work more like your options 2 or 3 if you think that sounds more fun or interesting. I might be inclined to houserule similarly if I wanted my player's pyromancer to feel more powerful, but if I were to houserule this, I wouldn't worry too much about whether it's "RAI" or not.

+1 especially for the last section.  When a tricky rules interaction doesn't have a clear RAW answer, or even when it does have a clear answer that doesn't make narrative sense (at all or for how magic should work in your game world), that's when GMs are supposed to decide what actually happens.

Spot on with RAI - unless you have a direct quote, or a personal relationship, RAI will be indeterminate. Empower DM, +1.

Fiery Soul does not change the outcome at all
You are correct that your scenario 1 is RAW. Let's break it down into 2 parts: damage and healing.
The Iron Golem's fire damage immunity is technically redundant
The golem has immunity to fire damage, but it also has a separate ability, Fire Absorption, that prevents it from taking fire damage. So even if you took the golem's fire damage immunity away entirely or replaced it with fire damage vulnerability, nothing would change, because Fire Absorption would still cause the golem to take no fire damage. I'm guessing that the golem is listed as immune to fire damage mainly to avoid confusion, since it ensures that regardless of whether you consult the golem's Damage Immunities or Traits, you get the same answer: it cannot take fire damage.
Healing is based on damage dealt, not damage taken
As for the healing aspect of Fire Absorption, this is also unaffected by Fiery Soul. The golem regains hit points equal to the fire damage dealt, not the fire damage it takes. We know this because otherwise it would never regain any hit points from this feature, since it cannot take any fire damage. Hence, effects such as resistance and vulnerability that modify the damage taken by the target are irrelevant for the purposes of determining how many hit points the golem regains.
Putting it together
Taking the above into account, we conclude that fire damage from a sorcerer with the Fiery Soul feature affects the Iron Golem in exactly the same way as all fire damage. In other words, the effect is the same regardless of whether the sorcerer has this feature or not.

Note: my answer here agrees with NathanS's on RAW, but my argument is slightly different, since I'm not using the "specific beats general" principle.

"fire damage immunity is technically redundant" is the key point here - and why this answer is better than the others.

None of the above
The correct RAW answer is that Fire Absorption will continue to work as written, because it is its own ability - not a modification of the resistance/immunity rules.
Because the golem is immune, Fiery Soul will turn this into resistance so, the golem will take half the damage. However, Fire Absorption says the golem “takes no damage and instead regains a number of hit points equal to the fire damage dealt.” This “no damage” is not immunity and is therefore unaffected by Fiery Soul.
So, a golem subjected to fire damage by someone with Fiery Soul still heals the full amount.

It feels unintuitive to me for the golem to heal for half the full amount of the damage. The intent of the player's ability is that their fire spells are 'more powerful' in that they now bypass immunity, and the intent of the golem's ability is that 'more powerful' fire damage sources heal it for more hp. If resistance reduces the incoming damage by half and then the golem heals that amount, why wouldn't immunity normally reduce the damage to 0 and then the golem heals for 0? If anything the player's ability should increase the amount healed.

@Kayndarr just reading what it says - there are no hidden rules so the only "intent" is what's written down.

yeah RAW I agree with your answer. It just feels like it's one of those cases where we're applying two separate rules as written and neither specifically addresses this edge case, leading to a result that doesn't fit with (at least my opinion of) the reality of the situation in the game world.

I agree with @Kayndarr. The intent of Fire Absorption is to invert the effect, turning damage into healing. The intent of Fiery Soul is to increase damage (by negating resistance). Hitting harder means that an inverted effect would then heal more. Healing more respects both of the effects, which alter the usual "it damages the normal amount" attack effect; instead it heals (due to Fire Absorption) more than normal (due to Fiery Soul).

If you interpret Fiery Soul to be purely about negating resistance and not dealing more damage (stress on the word dealing, not taking); which is also a reasonable interpretation; then the healing amount should remain unchanged (since this is based on what would normally have been the damage amount, which you just agreed is unchanged regardless of having Fiery Soul or not). Reducing the healing, however, does not make sense.

By this logic, wouldn't it always heal for 0 without Fiery Soul in the picture? The golem has fire immunity separately from Fire Absorption, so the amount of damage it would be "subjected to" by this interpretation of that phrase would always be 0 even before Fire Absorption reduced it to 0.

@Idran: See Ryan C. Thompson's answer; it makes a good argument that healing must be based on damage dealt not damage taken, because damage taken would indeed by 0 (except in cases where something bypassed its "Damage immunities: fire".)

@PeterCordes Oh, no, I agree with that; I meant specifically by the logic that Dale M was suggesting in this answer.

@Idran: Right, I agree with your criticism of this answer; I was pointing out that another answer was able to avoid that flaw while making a similar argument.

As noted, I think your argument is flawed. If Fire Absorption worked on damage taken, then since the Golem has Fire Immunity, it would never take damage in the first place, and thus never heal in the first place, which is clearly nonsensical.

Mostly I agree with NathanS' answer .. it's was my first take on it as well.  However, I'd figured I'd spell out another way to look at it ...
As a programmer, I tend to break things down modularly and handle them more logically, so let's try to do that here:

Golem makes a Dex save (with advantage) vs the Fireball.
This is regardless of if it's immune or not .. as pointed out in the other thread, it must make this save .. although some rules may allow it to choose to fail. The choice part we'll ignore here - it's not really the point of the argument at this time.

*Note: OP asked about Firebolt .. so save isn't really a point there .. Regardless, step 1 is get the incoming damage: make save, roll attack .. etc.  Rest flows as outlined below *
So the Saving throw is made and determines how much fire damage is incoming to the Golem. Whether he saved for half, or not and takes full .. is irrelevant .. let's just call this final incoming damage "X" Fire damage.

Incoming "X" Fire Damage.
Now that we know the value (ie "X"), we need to figure out what happens to it.  I find it easier at this point to break down all the pieces individually:

a) Golem will take "X" Fire damage.
b) Golem will Absorbs/Regains "X" Fire damage.
At this stage, it makes more sense (to me at least), to separate these items, and handle them separately.
Under normal situation (ie normal caster with no special abilities, and a normal Golem) ..
the (a)X Fire damage gets reduced to 0 due to immunity.
and the (b)X Fire "healing" is left untouched.
So net effect:  Golem :   gains  (b)X - (a)X  hp ... or just heals X hp from the fire damage.
However, with our pyro and the Fiery soul ability turning his immunity to resistance, it changes this slightly:
(a)X Fire damage hits the Golems (now) resistance, and is reduced to X/2
(b)X Healing is untouched/unaffected as it is "Subjected" to X Fire damage (resistances reduce it .. but so does immunity .. and Absorption still sees the original unmodified total .. so we stay consistent).
So in this scenario:  (b)X - (a)X/2 =  heals:  X/2
So if the fireball did 40 damage.  And  the Golem Made it's save.
X = 20
Normally  it would heal 20.
Vs Fiery Soul .. it would take 10 damage (since only resistant), and heal 20 (the amount of Fire damage it was subjected to).
Net change: Heal of 10.

Unlike the linked question about fireball, OP's question here is about firebolt, so there is no saving throw to complicate the matter.

oh true enough .. regardless .. first step is "determine the incoming damage" doesn't really change nature of the answer .. but good point ;)

There is no redundant text in fire absorption,  he has another no fire damage clause that is not immunity.

Fire Absorption a kind of Immunity
While Fire Absorption is written as a one-off ability, it is clearly on the Vulnerable/Normal/Resist/Immune scale.  Its redundant effect of dropping damage to 0 is just that; redundant text, making reading the ability clearer.
Corner cases demand DM interpretation
5e is not written as a board game; it is meant to be interpreted by a DM.  When corner cases occur, you shouldn't try to rule it like a judge at a board game competition; the rules are not physics.
It is best to treat 5e rules as a description of how an ability usually works.  If you ready an action to pass a spear when you are passed a spear, the readied action rules is how it usually works -- if you line up 10,000 peasants to do this in a chain, the readied action rules no longer describe how it works, as you are no longer in a "typical case".
Fire Absorption usually doesn't have the Immunity ability removed from under it, so this is a clear corner case.
Five plausible paths
First, Fire Absorption is to much greater than Immunity, the ability to penetrate mere immunity does nothing.
Second, Fire Absorption changes the damage suffered from 0 to half.  The healing remains based on full damage.  The result is the creature heals half as much.
This interpretation is roughly equivalent to a "board game" interpretation, where we consider the "damage is reduced to 0 HP" a redundant clause in Fire Absorption.
Third, we move Fire Absorption one step along the Vulnerability<->Immunity axis.  It just becomes Immunity.
Forth, Fire Absorption is stronger than Immunity narratively, but game-wise it is pretty much the same ("don't waste fire attacks on this").  We make the result be 1/4 damage instead of half, which respects both the narrative of "iron golems are more than immune to fire" and "pyromancers can burn even fire elementals".
Fifth, we assume Fire Absorption requires Immunity to function, and the ability nullifies the Immunity.  The creature is reduced to Resistance.
These are roughly in order of how generous they are to the player.
How to choose
Well, this is an 18th level subclass ability.  The core of it is that "you can burn anything, even the unburnable".  You can burn a creature made out of pure fire.
That pushes the scale towards the ability doing something.
On the other hand, it is reasonable in 5e that you'll sometimes run into a creature who nullifies your bag of tricks.  Monsters immune to weapons (or kinds of weapons) and magic both exist in 5e.  So long as they are rare, this is totally kosher -- this is a team game, not a solo one.
If I made a world or even adventure full of Iron Golems, I'd be tempted to not fully nullify the PC's ability as a Pyromancer, unless that player really likes puzzles.  If this was a one-off encounter, having the Pyromancer have to use a different bag of tricks that time would be totally reasonable.

Just.... no. Fire absorption is not immunity and separate

@Trish Can you distinguish between mechanics used to describe the game, and the imaginary world the mechanics are describing?  Your position is correct, in that the game uses distinct mechanics, and wrong, in that in the imaginary world the mechanics are describing they exist on a clear continuum.

There's three rules at play you forgot: 1) Spells and abilities do exactly what they say. 2) Specific beats general. 3) There's no redundant text in rules. As a result, while the effect for Fire Absorption and Immunity are the same, they are not the same when referenced by other things.

@Trish "There's no redundant text in rules." - that is not a rule of 5e D&D, and pretending it is is a #1 cause of peasant railguns.  There is piles of redundant text in 5e rules, as there should be, as without it you get reference spam.

If I were to run across this in a game, I'd assume that the Golem's trait is based off of their immunity to fire. So, the player's fire damage would be reduced to half, as the golem would be resistant instead of immune per the player's ability. Then, the golem regains those damage points as health.
For example, the player hits and deals a total of 50 points of fire damage. This is reduced by half to 25 points of fire damage. Thus, golem gains 25 points.
Hopefully that helps. Good luck!

This is a little unclear to me. Are you suggesting the golem would net zero points of damage (25 healing minus 25 damage) or that it would net 25 points healed (50 healing minus 25 damage)?

The golem turns fire damage into healing, the golem would heal the 25 points. So, instead of taking reduced damage, it takes reduced healing from fire damage.

Thanks - I'd suggest a fairly substantial edit to your answer to make that clearer. Here's how I would write it: "I interpret the golem's ability as turning fire damage into healing. By analogy with Immunity > Resistance halving the normal damage reduction, I would rule that this interaction halves the healing. For example, if a spell would do 50 points of damage normally, it would instead apply 50 points of healing to a golem. If the caster had this power, his spell would instead apply 25 points of healing, as if the golem had resistance to the effect".
